# Cassandra store data in BLOB

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

We are using Cassandra 3 and have come up with a modelling based on the initial requirements. Since there have been very frequent requirements changes, this model has subsequently changed many times as well. Hence considering these requirements and model changes, there has been no major improvement in terms of development. The team have decided to go with the BLOB data type and store the entire data in the BLOB. Can you please share the drawback to use BLOB such a  scenario. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

We migrated from Astyanax Cassandra 1.1 to CQL Cassandra 3.0 directly, so we still have a lot of column families which have value as BLOB.

Major issues we face right now are:

1) Difficult to visualize data directly from database: Biggest advantage of CQL is it supports SQL like queries, hence logging into cql terminal and getting results directly from there is saves a lot of time normally. If you use BLOB you will not be able to do all such things.

2) CQL performs better when your table has a well defined schema instead of using blob to store big chunk of data together.

If you are creating a new table, I will suggest to use Collections for your use case. You will be able to store different type of data and performance will also be good.

Nice slides comparing performance of schemaless tables and tables with scehma and collections. You can skip to slide 26 if you just want the summary.

https://www.slideshare.net/DataStax/migration-from-thrift-to-cql-brij-bhushan-ravat-ericsson-cassandra-summit-2016